# Google Analytics Goal tracking external referrals

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I have goal tracking setup on my site for a target url. It works insofar as it tracks all pageviews on my site leading up the goal. But it doesn't appear to be tracking the external referrer that the user came from initially, marking it as (entrance) and the step before that (not set).

Is this standard behaviour for goals not to record external referrer and how can I add referrer tracking to my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this data with the Visits with Conversions Segment. Switch to this segment via the Advanced segments, and then look at the Traffic Sources > Referrals panel.